# how to run batch file with task scheduler with option run whether logged on or not

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskscheduler

OS: Windows 10

I'm trying to run a batch file on Windows 10 from the Task Scheduler. I can run the batch file fine if I run it from the command prompt.

If I run it from the Task Scheduler to only run when the user is logged in, the task will run without any issues. However, when it runs when the user is not logged in, the Task Scheduler looks like it's running the file but nothing happens.

I've tried changing the batch file to nothing but the following line to ensure it's not because of what's in the batch file

I run it with higher privilege I allowed the user account to log as a batch file in local security policy

I still  hours to fix this issue but still the same problem when I run my batch file manually with option (run whether logged on or not) it will run but nothing happens

My configuration:[image]

[image]

Comment: To run the task when the user isn't logged on, Task Scheduler uses a service-for-user (S4U) batch logon (i.e. requires the batch logon right) to run the task in session 0, the non-interactive services session. You won't see a console in your interactive session. If it's not generating the report as it should, check the reported status of the task in Task Scheduler.

Comment: the problem is in the task scheduler its appear that the batch is already running but in fact, nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? As I said, you will not see any console or interactive response from the batch script since it gets run in a different session that doesn't even allow user interaction. This is normal, expected behavior when selecting this run option. What does Task Scheduler report as the exit code of the cmd.exe process? Is the report generated?

Comment: the problem is there report doesnt generated

Comment: I also asked about the exit status (Last Run Result) that Task Scheduler reports for the task (i.e. the cmd.exe process).

Comment: Try adding some logging to the script, such as `echo checkpoint_1 > C:\Temp\log.txt`.

Comment: it working now Thank you. the batch was running in the background

Comment: It is more than just "running in the background". Any process that doesn't create a window in the current session is running in the background. Even a console application such as cmd.exe can be run as a background process in the current session by using the creation flag `DETACHED_PROCESS`. The option you selected is much more; it causes the process to run in the non-interactive services session (session 0, whereas the first interactive session is 1), which nowadays by default doesn't create windows or support user interaction.